# Control aspect ratio of individual facets, facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to control the size/aspect ratio of an individual plot within a facet_wrap() plot?  Thanks,
-D

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/7c5454dcc04bc7b8/63345f975a361fa1?lnk=gst&q=aspect+ratio#63345f975a361fa1) thread may be of some use to you. And be sure to read about [gridExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html). The short answer is, I suspect, that you can but that it will involve some hacking and preserving things you *like* about faceting may be hard.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a solution simply to 'free' the x axis, y axis or both `scales` with either `scales = "free_x"`, `scales = "free_y"` or `scales = "free"`?

Here one example from the [facet_wrap documentation page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_wrap.html),

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free")
```